# Erro desconhecido no VDM do android-studio

Tags: apache-cordova, android-studio, ubuntu

Estou com problemas para criar um device no android-studio de pois de muito procurar na net decidi colocar uma pergunta aqui pra ver se alguémconsegue responder.

Utilizo Ubuntu 16.04 e o projeto em questão foi criado em PhoneGap, claro que importei somente a pasta android da pasta plataforms.
fato é que isto ja funcionou uma vez e não sei por que parou de funcionar.
Não encontrei nada na internet nem pista nenhum em nenhum arquivo de log

Ao abrir o VDM e selecionar qualquer uma das imagens eu vejo a seguinte tela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: isso deve ser problemas com suas variáveis de ambiente,
verifica se a "JAVA_HOME" está com o path correto em /home/user/.bash_profile ou /etc/profile, e declara uma variável "ANDROID_AVD_HOME": `export ANDROID_AVD_HOME="/home/usuario/.android/avd/"`.
avisa se corrigiu